# How to change Itemid in Joomla

Tags: joomla-3.x, itemid

I have had a joomla component 1.5 which is rebuild for joomla 3x
The URL structure is native URL Structure
index.php?option=com_productnews&view=list&Itemid=7

However - after rebuild the Itemid is changed to 102
index.php?option=com_productnews&view=list&Itemid=102

How to ensure or reswap in the Old Itemid to it
Pls advise

Comment: Is it a problem for SEO reasons or something else?  If it is, I'd probably turn on SEO friendly links and use the redirects manager to redirect the old URLs. It's not really good practise to show the users the parameters.  If your productnews component is bespoke then you might need to write a router.

Comment: Similar topic: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/16245/301-redirects-for-old-non-sef-urls-to-new-sef-ones-with-new-article-ids/16248#16248

Answer (score -1):

Just create a redirect in the `.htaccess` file from the old URL to the new URL.

Comment: This will break the menu item with the id 7 in the migrated site forever. I know what you want to archive, it's a simple solution but not the best way.

Comment: How will it do that? Could you please elaborate? The redirect includes the full link, and not just the item id. I also noticed that you downvoted my answer but your answer is exactly the same as mine, albeit longer and somewhat wrong.

Comment: I did a mistake, redirecting cannot break a menu item with the same id in OPs context, because the url would be different and therefore not matching the redirect rule.